# How to dispatch these functions in Objective C to not lock Main thread?

Tags: design-patterns, multithreading, objective-c, dispatch

There's a large shared object (kind of OpenGL context) in my project.
It is accessed from multiple threads.
To ensure only one thread at the moments is using `SHARED_OBJECT`, mutex (kind of `NSRecursiveLock`) is used.

The problem is that sometimes `MAIN_THREAD` is waiting a lot while some `BG_THREAD` is doing something with `SHARED_OBJECT`.

I am not supposed to change architecture (to rewrite this mutex scheme). 
The current problem lies in following: 
There is `my_backround_func` (takes a lot of time), which is called before `main_thread_func1`(takes few milliseconds) and `main_thread_func2`.

These functions are spread all over the project. 
To fix the problem, I created singleton class `Dispatcher`, which lets `main_thread_func*` to be registered, and lets `my_backround_func` to ask if all `main_thread_funcs` were already executed.

It uses Objective C mechanisms like `NSStringFromSelector` and "`_cmd`".

At the start of the program I register functions:

```
[[MyBackgroundFunctionDispatcher dispatcher] setCanCallBgFunc:NO forSelector:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(main_thread_func1:))];

[[MyBackgroundFunctionDispatcher dispatcher] setCanCallBgFunc:NO forSelector:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(main_thread_func2:))];
```

And at the end of `main_thread_func1` and `main_thread_func2` I call

```
[[MyBackgroundFunctionDispatcher dispatcher] setCanCallBgFunc:YES forSelector:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
```

All this time background thread is waiting:

```
while ( ![[MyBackgroundFunctionDispatcher dispatcher] setCanCallBgFunc] )
    sleep_ms(10);
```

So, I ensured that background function will be caller AFTER registered main thread functions. `MyBackgroundFunctionDispatcher` can be extended to hold registered functions not only for `my_backround_func`, but for `my_backround_func1`, `my_backround_func2`.

While the solution looks ugly and I suspect I miss some good pattern.

Could you give any advices please?

Comment: Why NSStringFromSelector? A selector itself does all you need.